# Why isn't Zebulon near Sidon but Asher?

Tags: old-testament, jacob

In Genesis 49:13 is written:

> "Zebulon shall dwell by the haven of the sea;
>   He shall become a haven for ships,
>   And his border shall adjoin Sidon.

But if I take a look on the maps, which are created for the twelve tribes, Zebulon is not near Sidon and neither at the seaside. Instead, Asher has the place I thought Zebulon should get. Was there something I missed, or why was Jacob's words "false"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maps of the tribes of Israel contain a lot of guesswork. The tribe of Asher is one of them. No one is even sure whether Asher had a continuous territory.

Answer (score -1):

Chuck Smith commented on this passage by saying, Zebulan has yet to do what God through Joseph said they can and they will do. 
Like many Christian, some people don't enter into the full potential God has destined for them because of distractions. 
Along with idolatry, and disobedience there was a lot of fearful people amongst the early tribes and this may have contributed to then not yet reaching their full potential and God given abilities.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. There seems to be some contradiction between this prophecy in Genesis and how the tribes' territories were assigned in Genesis. Whether or not the tribes were faithful and conquered their full territories isn't the issue.